# Timezone in Cloud Foundry

Tags: cloud-foundry

What is default timezone when I publish my app in the cloud ? How do I change the timezone if there's such option ?

Any reference to this feature is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The clock on run.pivotal.io is set to UTC. If you're deploying to there you would have to adjust the time using your app. If you are using your own instance of Cloud Foundry and wanted all the components running in a different timezone other than UTC I believe you would have to create a bosh errand to re-configure the timezone on each job.

Personally, I think your best option is to stick with UTC and offset using your app code.